# How can I highlight specific words in a .txt file using scintilla or any other method in C#?

Tags: c#, highlight

I am reading a text file using regex and I want to highlight text in that file. Is this possible using C#?

Comment: If WinForms, place the text file contents into a RichTextBox() and then you can format it however you want.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to read the contents of a text file and display them in a window with words matching specific regex patterns highlighted. It would not be possible to edit the file to display those words as highlighted in any given text editor- .txt documents do not have formatting.